# Is there a better way to write this if statements?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logic

I started recently as a developer and I am still struggling a bit with the way I write my code.

Is there a better way to write this two if-statements? How would you write it and why?

Java code:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteItem(final ConfigurationType type, final long itemId, final boolean force) {
    this.applicationNameUtils.throwOnInvalidApplication(type.getApplication());
    final ConfigurationItemModel item =
        this.configurationItemRepository.findByApplicationAndTopicAndId(type.getApplication(), type.getTopic(), itemId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(itemId, "Configuration Item"));
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) && Boolean.FALSE.equals(force)) {
        throw new ContentModificationOnlyException("Configuration Item cannot be deleted");
    }
    if ((Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) || Boolean.FALSE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly())) && Boolean.TRUE.equals(force)) {
        this.assignmentService.deleteAssignmentsByItem(item);
        this.configurationInstanceRepository.deleteByItem(item);
        this.configurationItemRepository.deleteById(itemId);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I can somehow combine this two in a if-else.

Comment: `Boolean.FALSE.equals(force)` is unnecessary complicated.  `boolean force` is a primitive boolean, so just using `!force` will give the exact same behavior. Using `Boolean.FALSE.equals` or `Boolean.TRUE.equals` for comparing usually only makes sense when you are dealing with non primitive `Boolean` types and want to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: I would suggest first reviewing your logic as this looks not logically correct
(Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) || Boolean.FALSE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly())

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov `(Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) || Boolean.FALSE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly())` could make sense if `item.getContentModificationOnly()` would return a `Boolean`. In that case the statement would resolve to `false` for the case that `item.getContentModificationOnly()` would return `null`.  For a primitive `boolean` this statement of course wouldn't make sense as the primitive type can't be `null` and the statement would therefor always resolve to `true`.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yeah in this case `contentModificationOnly` is declared as Boolean in `ConfigurationItemResource` so I have to use Boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't care about `item.getContentModificationOnly()` is true or false in the second if-statement since your code is `(Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) || Boolean.FALSE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly())`. So if your logic is right I suggest you code like this:

```java
if (fore) {
    this.assignmentService.deleteAssignmentsByItem(item);
    this.configurationInstanceRepository.deleteByItem(item);
    this.configurationItemRepository.deleteById(itemId);
} else if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(item.getContentModificationOnly()) {
    throw new ContentModificationOnlyException("Configuration Item cannot be deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First if condition

```
 if (item.getContentModificationOnly() && !force) {
```

Second If condition

```
if ((item.getContentModificationOnly() || !item.getContentModificationOnly()) && force) {
```

The below code will always return true

```
(item.getContentModificationOnly() || !item.getContentModificationOnly())
```

so modify second if stmnt to just

`if (force)`{

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the return type `item.getContentModificationOnly()`. If it's **B**oolean, than the second statement can be reduced to

```
if(item.getContentModificationOnly() != null && force)
```

If the return type of `item.getContentModificationOnly()` is **b**oolean, than the statement can be reduced to

```
if(force)
```

and the answer of @LiLittleCat above if correct.